# Access DifferentialIK outside of Drake

Tags: python, drake

Is there a way for a downstream python project that is using installed pydrake (either from a downloaded binary or cmake of a local version) to access [DifferentialIK](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/examples/manipulation_station/differential_ik.py)?  I can't seem to import it using an anything similar to `from pydrake.all import DifferentialIK`.

Answer (score 1):

This file is not part of `pydrake`, and I don't believe it's part of the install tree.

I've filed an issue to address this:

https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13548